# Question about if statement format

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

The following code prints "Odd" no matter what number I put in, why doesn't it print "Even" when given an even number as an argument?

```
if [[ 'echo "$1%2" | bc' =~ 0 ]]
then
        echo "Even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching the regular expression `0` to the *string* `echo "$1%2" | bc`.  The string does not contain a `0`, so the `else` branch is taken.

To test whether `$1` is odd or even, use an arithmetic test instead:

```
if (( $1 % 2 == 0 )); then
    echo even
else
    echo odd
fi
```

The `(( ... ))` bit is an arithmetic evaluation.  It will evaluate the expression inside and its value will be the result of that expression.  The `if` statement can then act on the result.

To use `bc` as you intended to do:

```
if [ "$( printf '%s %% 2\n' "$1" | bc )" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo even
else
    echo odd
fi
```

That is, use a command substitution (the `$(...)` bit) to insert the result of running the command within it, then compare that to zero using `-eq` (for an arithmetic comparison).

If using `printf` feels funny, then use

```
if [ "$( echo "$1 % 2" | bc )" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo even
else
    echo odd
fi
```

but see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)".

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes prevent the $1 from being replaced.  Experiment with quoting parts of that statement to get the  results you want.

Comment: It's meant as a pipe, I am piping the result of echo to bc.
edit: ah okay :)

Comment: It would still compare the command as a string though.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, ... why? The core issue here is that `test` (or `[[`) gets `'string' =~ 0` as an argument - whether it contains %, $ and | or not!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use a simpler and independent solution (only using `bash`, cause this one depends on `bc` too), your try was almost correct; simply change **'** for **`** (a backtick):

```
if [[ `echo "$1%2" | bc` =~ 0 ]]
then
        echo "Even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
```

what you tried:

```
'echo "$1%2" | bc'
```

what you meant:

```
`echo "$1%2" | bc`
```

---

On the other hand, you are using [`=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same
>   precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right
>   of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and
>   matched accordingly (as in regex3)).

Probably, this **is not** what you want, but, in this particular case, will work just fine: `n%2` no matter what natural number `n` is, always will give you `0` or `1`. `1` (when the number is `odd`) doesn't match the regex `0`, so, you are safe... but, beware: this could be wrong in another case: the regex `0` will match `0`, but `10`,`707`,`2.71828182845905`, or anything with a `0` too. In a case like this, you want to use `=`, instead of `=~`.

Also, notice that `$(...)` is preferred over the backticks.